# Probability inequality with given EX

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> For two independent variables $$X, Y$$ we know:
>   $$P(X=x)=\frac{3^x}{e^3\times x!}$$
>   $$P(Y=y)=\frac{2}{3^y}$$
>   $$E[(X-4\times Y+6)^2]=24$$

Could anyone help me proof that:
$$P(X \geq 4Y)\leq\frac{2}{3}$$

What's more I'm looking for intuition what exactly means $$P(X \geq 4Y)$$ It is easy to imagine situation $$P(X \geq C) $$ where $$C$$ is some constant value, but $X$ and $Y$ are random variables!

Comment: There shouldn't be some parenthesis in the $E[\dots]=24$?

Comment: @Lovsovs , No, it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

we can write $x-4y\ge z$
so $P(X-4Y\ge 0) \le \frac {2}{3}$
as in this type of problem we have to find the set of points $C_z $ such that the event ${Z\ge z}$ is equal to $\{X-4Y \ge z\}$ in this case ,is also equal to thwe points $\{X,Y \in C_z\}$.

then [image: yellow]

as in your case $z=0 $ hence the line will pass through the origin and the region that is to be taken under consideration is the upper part of the line